# Flutter Local Notification onSelectNotification function argument type can't be assinged

Tags: flutter, dart, types, push-notification, flutter-local-notification

I am using [Local Notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) for my app and I am trying to set up the `onSelectNotification` but I can not make it work. This is how I `init`:

```
 Future initialize() async {
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');

    IOSInitializationSettings iosInitializationSettings =
        IOSInitializationSettings();

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: androidInitializationSettings,
            iOS: iosInitializationSettings);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings, onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification
    );
  }
```

And my `onSelectNotification`:

```
  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    print(payload);
  }
```

But Flutter is complaining:

> The argument type 'Future Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future Function(String?)?'.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation about this and nowhere else.. What am I missing her?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
Future<void> onSelectNotification(String? payload) async {...}
```

instead of

```
Future<void> onSelectNotification(String payload) async {...}
```

It's missing the **?** on your `String payload`

Answer (score -1):

Use onSelectNotification to Future < **dynamic** > instead.

```
Future<dynamic> onSelectNotification(payload) async {
   // implement logic
   print("onSelectNotification : " + payload);
}
```